# Trigger of function not happening when combo box selected

Tags: angularjs

I have created a tree using the bento component. What i am trying to do is have a combo box  wherein i select a value and all the tree nodes matching the value get selected. However the function associated with the combo box change event is not getting triggered.

**Angular JS Code**

```
var app = angular.module('BentoUIApp', ['bento.modern', 'wj', 'bento.d3', 'aa.formExtensions', 'aa.notify']);

angular.module('BentoUIApp').controller('DbConnectionCtrl', [
  '$scope',
  '$timeout',
  function ($scope, $timeout) {
    'use strict';

        $scope.dbConnections = [];


    $scope.filteritems = [
      {ID: '1', Title: 'devwatch_w_b'},
      {ID: '2', Title: 'None'}

    ];


    $scope.selectOption = function(selectedVal,item) {
            dbItems = [];
            alert("function selected");


      $scope.dbConnections = [];


            if(selectedVal == 1){
                $scope.tree.forEach(function(parent) {


                     //dbItems = parent.items;
                    var i;
                    for(i = 0; i < parent.items.length; i++) {
                        if(item.name == parent.items[i].name){
                            var idx = $scope.dbConnections.indexOf(parent.items[i]);
                                if(idx==-1){
                                    parent.items[i].selected=true;
                                    $scope.dbConnections.push(parent.items[i]);
                                    //parent.items[i].selected=false;
                                }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        }   

    // Initialize callback status model
    $scope.treeCallBackStatus = 'N/A';

    /*** Callback functions ***/
    $scope.selectedItemChanged = function (item) {
      /* To cancel user selection */
      //return false;

            var idx = $scope.dbConnections.indexOf(item);


       $scope.treeCallBackStatus = 'Selected Item changed: "' + item.name + '"';
            if(idx==-1 && !item.isselected){
                $scope.dbConnections.push(item);
             console.log($scope.dbConnections);
            }
            else{
                $scope.itemCollapsed(item);
                }

    };

    $scope.itemExpanded = function (item) {
      $scope.treeCallBackStatus = 'Item Expanded: "' + item.name + '"';
    };

    $scope.itemCollapsed = function (item) {
      $scope.treeCallBackStatus = 'Item Collapsed: "' + item.name + '"';
       var idx = $scope.dbConnections.indexOf(item);
       $scope.dbConnections.splice(idx, 1);
    };

    $scope.checkboxClicked = function (item) {
      if (item.checked) {
        $scope.treeCallBackStatus = 'Item Checked: "' + item.name + '"';
      } else {
        $scope.treeCallBackStatus = 'Item Unchecked: "' + item.name + '"';
      }
    };




    // Initialize FEF Tree Data
    function init() {
        $scope.tree = [];

        var parentItem={
            collapsed:true,
             expandOnly:true,
            hideCheckbox:true,
            iconName:"",
            id:0,
            items:[],
            name:"CS CI"
      }

      $scope.tree.push(parentItem);

      // Children of A
      var itemA1 = {
        id             : 11,
        name           : "devwatch_w_b",
        hideCheckbox        :true,
        parent         : parentItem
      };
      var itemA2 = {
       id             : 12,
       name           : "qawatch_w_b",
       hideCheckbox     :true,
       parent         : parentItem
      };
      var itemA3 = {
        id             : 13,
        name           : "devwatch_w_b",
        hideCheckbox        :true,
        parent         : parentItem
      };

      parentItem.items.push(itemA1);
      parentItem.items.push(itemA2);
      parentItem.items.push(itemA3);
     }
    // ... (edited for brevity) ...

    // To simulate server loading with one sencond delay
    $timeout(function () {
      init()
    }, 1000);

    }
]);
```

I have attached the JSFiddle code [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ThomsonKrish/1u5dko2o/66/)

What is that i am missing? I am adding the selected item, so that later i can refer it for another requirement.

How to make the ng-change event working, though the function associates with it is in the controller?

Comment: Found the issue and resolved it. Updated the JSfiddle.

Comment: You can answer your own question btw